# Can't use HTTP endpoints of Virtuoso for my newly created graph FCT147

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am trying to do a get call for the data that i have inserted in my new graph using http endpoint `http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth?graph-uri=FCT147`,
but it returns a `500` failed request with HTML response as

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>SPARQL Graph Protocol request failed</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP/1.1 500 Request Failed</h1>
    <h3>Error 22023</h3>
    <xmp>The graph URI <FCT147> is relative and can be passed to SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store endpoint only in some PUT or
            POST requests</xmp>
</body>

</html>
```

When i try to do the same request with a already existing graph for example

```
http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth?graph-uri=http://localhost:8890/sparql
```

it works fine and gives me the response.

I don't understand how can i get response for my newly created graph. Please help

Comment: `The graph URI <FCT147> is relative` -- it is passing that the full (absolute) URI is required. It will start with a scheme name.

Comment: How can i get the full URI, i tried to look almost everywhere but didn't find any useful information

Comment: Ask the query `SELECT * {GRAPH ?g {}}` - that lists the graph names (in any SPARQL endpoint).

Comment: When i run this query it return the following message,  _star_fake :1, are you suggesting this is the absolute URI of my graph that i created?

Comment: Post this i ran the command select distinct ?g {graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}} which returned me the relative name only FCT147

Comment: Then you created it with a relative URI. I'm afraid to make it work, it needs to be absolute URI because the system tests at some points.

Comment: I think you are right i created a new graph with name http://data.exapmple.com/vocab/comp/ and now i am able to retrieve the records, it just wasn't working for FCT147, i however still dont understand why it is like that maybe i need to learn more on Virtuoso, Thank you @AndyS

Answer (score 0):

How did you upload the data in the apparent `FCT147` graph? As indicated by others, the `graph-url` being passed must be an absolute URI, which the Graph Protocol UI also enforces when uploading data. Thus, I assume you uploaded the graph data via some other means?

The `SELECT distinct ?g {GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o}` query can be used to obtain the complete list of graphs in a Virtuoso database, and as indicated any graph identifier passed to the Graph Protocol interface must be an absolute URI...